# How do I write all the records from a massive MongoDB collection into a csv file without taking up all RAM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, memory, mongoengine

I have a collection in which I had uploaded the contents of a `xml` file that was 4GB. It had around 14000000 records.
I need to write those records to a `csv` file. I was using the following code snippet thinking it will work fine as objects are read/written as and when they are required. However that doesn't seem to be the case. After running the code my RAM gives up.
I am using `mongoengine` to use the underlying *PyMongo* library for DB operations.

```
import csv
from xml_to_db import Users #This is my collection definition in a separate file

extract_user_fields = ['Id', 'Reputation', 'UpVotes', 'DownVotes']
users_file = 'users.csv'

with open(users_file, 'a', newline='') as f:
    for user_docs in Users.objects:
        user_document_dict = dict()
        for key in extract_user_fields:
            user_document_dict[key] = user_docs[key]
        # for simplicity we will update the csv file as soon as we have a record
        # write this document to the csv file
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, extract_user_fields)
        writer.writerow(user_document_dict)
```

In the [`mongoengine` docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#) it isn't mentioned anywhere that Querying the DB this way can lead to memory issues if the collection is huge.

Moreover I can't pinpoint what line is responsible for the memory explosion.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) for this -- it's what it's made for.

Comment: @willis thanks a lot for that. I fired up a query. Hopefully it goes well.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoengine caches all Documents fetched by a query set by default, use the following to disable that behaviour:
`for user_docs in Users.objects.no_cache():`